# The npm http package only provides a package.json, no javascript files

Tags: javascript, http, npm

I installed a npm package that had 'http' as a dependency, so I installed that as well.  All that was downloaded by npm for 'http' was a package.json file which referenced a non-existent index.js file.  Is the index.js indeed missing from package.json or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using systemJS as a library loader.

Comment: This is really weird and looks more like a bug than a question

Comment: `http` is part of Node's [standard library](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html). Apparently, someone _also_ created a package with the same name, but you don't need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the package that I'm installing that has 'http' as a dependency is using a "require('http')" line in its index.js, and that is causing the browser to look for it and not find it.  A 404 error is generated, and the page stops execution.

Comment: The library I was trying to get to work is 'couch'.  The 'node-couchdb', 'couchnode', and 'couchdb-promises'.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** you can't run server-side modules inside a browser.

From what I understand, you're trying to use server-side JavaScript modules inside of a browser, which isn't going to work. Browser have (very) limited abilities to set up network connection, or read from local file systems.

The `http` dependency that you're refering to is part of the Node standard library. So for Node apps, running server-side, it's always available.

In your case, you assumed that because `require('http')` didn't work (in the browser), you needed to install a separate package for that ([this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http)).

But even *if* that package was working properly (it isn't), it wouldn't have worked inside of a browser because it depends on other modules inside the Node standard library, that also aren't available in a browser.

I don't know if CouchDB has a REST API itself that you would be able to use from the browser, but if not, you're going to have to implement a server-side API that will act as go-between between the browser and CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

From the browser, to talk to CouchDB, try the PouchDB library (https://pouchdb.com/) and put the URL to your CouchDB in the constructor.  It's intended for connecting to a local PouchDB (javascript implementation of CouchDB) but their APIs are identical.  Or, try actually using a local PouchDB and then syncing between the two databases.